# Passing INT in bundle and placing it as drawable?

Tags: android, bundle, drawable

I'm fetching notification icons and they are returning ints. I pass this through a bundle set them like so:

```
int pic = bundle.getInt("image");
        iView.setImageResource(pic);
```

But the image then turns transparent and logcat is saying it failed getting the entry in package 0. How can I apply it as a drawable correctly?

Comment: Where are you fetching from ? Are they R.drawable.imagename ints or just some random integer number ?

Answer (score 0):

The value is a resource identifier that exists in the source application's package. You need to load the application's resources, then load the drawable from that.

```
int resId = bundle.getInt("image");
String package = event.getPackageName();
Resources res = getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication(package);
Drawable d = res.getDrawable(resId);
iView.setImageResource(d);
```

Comment: Just FYI, this is only true if resolving resources from another application (i.e. *not your own*). This is a very rare use case but it's unclear what exactly the OP's use case is.

Comment: This seems like a much better way than I am currently doing it. Figured it out while trying to parse a bitmap. Solution posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24918870/2423004

But if this method works better then I will report back as soon as I can. 

@kcoppock Another application. Incoming notifications, actually.